# How to pause Selenium WebDriver Script and enter CAPTCHA, and then script starts again

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, captcha

I am automating an page where after entering credentials,a user has to manually enter a CAPTCHA -

What I need to do :

1. I need to stop the script at that point
2. User will manually fill the CAPTCHA
3. Script will restart after lets say 3 seconds
4. Script will click on login button

Answer (score 1):

here is the approach to handle captch to enter manually...

1. script will stop as soon as below code execute..
   it prompts user to enter captch value.

   String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter captch Input:", "Dialog for Input", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
   and entered value assign to captch text
2. then script will continue execution

Answer (score 0):

If you have using java then use

```
Thread.sleep(3000)
```

it will pause execution for 3 seconds, same you can use in other language

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, I was using python with selenium, I searched a lot for a simple solution and here it is finally!!

```
import time

# All your automation code until captcha

time.sleep(5) 

#Wait for 5 sec
# All your automation code after the captcha entry
```